# Does not show variable in ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngmodel

I export a class into a module and i initialize but i can't use it on Front with ngModel. I was able to use it before but not now and i do not perceive what it's wrong as dont show me any error message. Help :c
I'm sure that it's something very simple but I am new on Angular on Ionic.

I'm trying to make a stopwatch and I have an interval on the class that incremente the time. I use that variable to show the time on Frontend using ngModel on a  (I'm working on Ionic 4). I tried this before and it work great but then I tried to add a service to initialize the class from the constructor and I mess it up. I already tried delete all the project and start again from the last commit on Github (was yesterday when everything was fine) and make copy/paste the code that should work but didn't.

This is on Front-End [home.page.html]:

```
  <ion-item class="container-stopwatch" lines="none">
    <ion-title>
      <ion-datetime #timer [ngModel]="this.timer.TIME" text-center readonly=true displayFormat="mm:ss"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-button (click)="reset()" *ngIf="show_reset" text-lowercase size="small" slot="end" color="light"><p style="color:red;">reset</p></ion-button>
  </ion-item>
```

And this is part of the file .ts of that page [home.page.ts]:

```
import { Timer } from './timer';
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController) {
    console.log(this.timer.TIME); // print '00:00:00.000'
  }

  public timer: Timer = new Timer();
  public list_times: string[] = []

  play() {
    console.log(this.timer);
    this.timer.run();
  }
}
```

And finally this is part of the class Timer [timer.ts]:

```
export class Timer{
   constructor(){
      this.reset();
      this.isStart = false;
   }

   // Time of the timer
   public TIME:string = "00:00:00.000";
```

[image]

On console print the value of this.timer.TIME ('00:00:00.000') on home.page.ts constructor, but if the class are correctly initialized on that file, why I can't use the same variable on Front-End?

**EDIT:**

I replicate the problem here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nwahpb

Comment: Ok, so ion-datetime takes a date, you are only using part of a date (the time part) try using a complete datetime. Make TIME = '2019-01-01T13:47:20.789'

Comment: You cannot show "00:00:00.000" this type of values on `ion-datetime`

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda actually I can. I wrote `value="00:00:00.000"` on the ion-datetime tag and display the format HH:mm:ss like "00:00:00"

Comment: @GabrielLopez I tried with that format and still not display nothing :T

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xhrzwh then we can give you a solution

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nwahpb

Answer (score 0):

Is `HomePage` your component? If yes, I think you're missing the `@component()` decorator. Moreover, I think `[ngModel]="this.timer.TIME"` should be `[ngModel]="timer.TIME"`. It's also a good idea to check your app.module.ts. Are you declaring your component?

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually I have the @Component but I didn't paste it. I update the post with that. And I try without `this`but still not working :c

Comment: Hmm... Try to use [(ngModel)] instead [ngModel]

Comment: Neither adding `#timer="ngModel"` to the ion-datetime tag by the way :T

Comment: Instead of put it into an `ion-datetime`, try just {{ timer.TIME }} just to check the binding

Comment: Like this: `<ion-datetime #timer ngModel="{{timer.TIME}}" text-center readonly=true displayFormat="HH:mm:ss"></ion-datetime>`?

Comment: I meat to put it on the body, like: `<p> {{ timer.TIME }} </p>`

Comment: Oh, I tried that and nop, doesn't display anywhere. I wrote like this `<ion-title>
            {{timer.TIME}}
        </ion-title>`

Comment: Do you have this code available on a repository or something like that?